# Attempted downgrade from GRUB2 to GRUB; can't boot into ubuntu anymore

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

So I just did a clean install of windows 7 ultimate and installed ubuntu 12.10 beside it. I kept the windows bootloader in the mbr at the advice if my tutorial (i used easyBCD to enable an option for grub2) and installed grub2 to the /boot partition that I made for sda5. If it matters, I set / as sda6, /home as sda7 and swap as sda8. I wanted to encrypt my windows partition with truecrypt, and I read to downgrade from grub2 to grub first, so I did (or at least attempted to). the code I used to replace grub2 with grub came from post #4 on this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1330347#4

However, it leads me into a command line titled "GNU GRUB version 2.00-7ubuntu11". I don't know why it still says version 2. Anyways, I can't even boot into Ubuntu now. From what I understand of grub (a very limited understanding admittedly), I need to use the root, kernel, and boot command to boot up ubuntu. But the problem is that root and kernel don't even exist as commands in the grub terminal. I pressed tab to list all the commands and they weren't among them. Typing them into the terminal yields no result. How do I get into ubuntu now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In grub2, the commands you are looking for are `linux`, `initrd`, and `boot`.  For example:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic
boot
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Recommended Repair` of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

[image]